# null is not an object Sqlite + ReactNative expo Typescript

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, expo

I made login page and now i'm trying to replace simple user.js to Sqlite Database (react-native-sqlite-storage).
When i launch my project with database, i get this error.

[image]

My Code

```
import {openDatabase} from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
var db = openDatabase({name : 'UserDatabase.db'});
const SignInScreen = ({navigation}) => {
const [userName, setuserName] = useState();
const [userContact, setuserContact] = useState();
const [userAddress, setuserAddress] = useState();
let register_user = () =>
{
    console.log(userName, userContact, userAddress);
db.transaction(function(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql(
        'INSERT INTO table_user(user_name, user_name, user_password) VALUES(?, ?,?)',
    [userName, userContact, userAddress],
    (tx, result) =>
    {console.log('Result', result.rowAffected);
    if (result.rowAffected > 0)
    {
    onPress: () => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
    }
    }
        )
})}
//And Button
  <TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.signIn}
  onPress={() => {register_user}}
            >
                
    <Text> Check //Here linegradient 1)</Text>
         
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: What's the Question? Console.log(db) please.

Comment: @Gismo1337 ,  I can't connect sqlite properly, despite the guides, that i watched...  Question is about a possibility, why that happen. "Consoloe.log" - i create database like
`const db = SQLite.openDatabase(
  {
    name : 'MainDb',
    location : 'default',
  },
  ()=> {},
    error => {console.log(error)}
);`
But when the page is rendering, i get 2 errors (error above and "main" has not been registered). I try to use SqliteWeb, but i stuck in async reading. 
In general i try to create database and a table in page and i get this 2 errors, don't have idea, how to deal with this..

Comment: Console.log(db) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem consist from creating connection in separate file (must be create in App).